# REST API - should JSON content be HtmlEncoded?

Tags: angular, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, xss

We have a setup with angular front-end app and asp.net core web api backend. API responds with json.
Question is, should json properties be html encoded or not?

I can see reasons for both: pro and con.

On one hand, REST API should be client agnostic (thus, shouldn't care about html in particular), on the other hand it feels a bit risky to rely on client-side XSS prevention alone.

Thoughts?

Comment: would be interesting from these 'close' voters to hear a bit of reasoning: how to address this kind of questions where its not that clear what best practice is.

Comment: The question is not opinion-based, but possible duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386340/should-rest-api-return-escaped-user-generated-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- Different encodings are needed for different contexts. Baking in html-encoding for all data may not always be good, especially if you somehow write into a Javascript context, where it is useless against XSS. So from this perspective I'd consider JSON as data, which only needs json encoding and not html. Of course client-side data binding or something else needs to take care of encoding or safe binding then.
- If JSON is returned in an API call, the content-type of the response is crucial. It needs to be `application/json`, otherwise the json endpoint itself will be vulnerable to XSS if it contains `<script>` etc.
- If you write JSON data into a script block for example to initialize a variable, it gets tricky. Consider the following:

```
<script>
  var data = "{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}";
</script>
```

This looks fine, but take a look at this:

```
<script>
  var data = "{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': '</script><script>alert(1)</script>'}";
</script>
```

It looks like a simple string, but the browser is primarily an html parser. It finds stuff between <script> and </script> and executes that as Javascript. The first `</script>` inside the string happens to be paired with the very first `<script>` tag, and the first open tag in the string will start a completely new script, thus resulting in XSS.

So if you are intending to write JSON into the html as part of Javascript (a very common use), you need to encode JSON contents to HTML unfortunately. It's much better to avoid this and download data separately.

Comment: those are some  very good points! thanks for that! content-type is always application/json, of course and i also like the ide of json being data only (which especially makes sense if non-html clients consume api). so,  if i read you correctly you lean more towards client deciding weather it should htmlencode some parts of json or not?

Comment: Yes, I think it should not be encoded apart from encoding values for json itself so that the jaon structure is intact. From there it's the job of the consumer of this data to take care of any further encoding, eg. html or javascript encoding against xss. One reason to do html encoding of json values can be if you want to write it into the page to initialize a js variable, but I think it's better to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, i agree. I will mark your post as answer, lets just clarify one detail: what exactly do you mean by 'writing json value into the page to initialize js variable'? Thanks!

Comment: @deezg Based on the question tags I suppose a .net example makes the most sense. When you have a cshtml with something like `<script> var data = @jsonData; </script>`, or even worse, `<script> var data = @Html.raw(jsonData); </script>`

Comment: ah, right right, now i see :). no, nothing like that, of course. no cshtml things at all, .net part is pure REST API. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, had to think about it, but I would do:
No additional HTML encoding on top of JSON. Make sure that you set the proper Content Type. If you have "unsafe" data fields, that you consider especially dangerous, then you can specify those in your documentation as HTML encoded without breaking JSON in general.

So both of the following lines are fine:

```
{'data': '<script>alert(1)</script>'} # Normal, how I would do it
{'data': '&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;'} # unsafe data field which is documented as html encoded
```

Comment: i wasn't completely precise but thank you for making a good point that no encoding should be done on top of json but just on (risky) properties. I've updated my question to be explicit about that.

Comment: regarding your answer, yes, that is one of the options. question that arises then is how to handle that on mobile clieng, for example? also, on client, all properties should be treated as risky because of the Stored XSS type regardless of input validation. I've seen examples where people actually send back 2 versions of json in every response: encoded and raw. but not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: I would value more the clean API and try to tighten the data insight of my JSON then the complete JSON output. For example I would not "echo" back the input of variables in an Validation Error response, to prevent possible injections. (and yes clients should treat all fields as risky)